# How to install the latest version of octave in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package, ubuntu-14.04, octave

**sudo apt-get build-dep octave** is not working. The error message is **"E: Build-Depends dependency for octave cannot be satisfied because the package automake cannot be found"**. I have modified the */etc/apt/sources.list* file with deb replaced by deb-src. Even when I try **sudo apt-get install octave**, an error is displayed that the package is not located.

Answer (score 3):

**Octave packages** http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems
Many Octave packages are also distributed by your Linux distribution. These are tested to work the best with your Octave version. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install octave-control octave-image octave-io octave-optim octave-signal octave-statistics
```

**Octave's Personal Package Archive (PPA) for Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

You can also Try with

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.0.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf octave-4.0.0.tar.bz2
cd octave-4.0.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

More version are available at ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave

Or

Adding a line to your /etc/apt/sources.list

**amd64**: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libgraphicsmagick3/filelist

**i386**: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libgraphicsmagick3/download